# Code igniter 404 page not found error

Tags: codeigniter

I have developed a web application on code igniter. This is the first time i am working on code-igniter After developing a web application on my localhost its working fine. But when I hosted the site in server the main index page was opening but the sub pages showing `"404 page not found error"`. Can you please guide me.Here is my htacess file

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*

RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php?/$1 [L]`
```

and in my `routes.php` I have added following line

```
$route['about'] = 'mycontroller/about';
```

Comment: What you've in your `config.php` at `$config['index_page'] = '';` ? it should be around line 34.

Comment: Have a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28801605/my-codeigniter-cant-jump-to-the-right-address-from-the-index-php you will see some htaccess try them out.

Comment: I replaced $config['index_page'] = ' index.php'; with $config['index_page'] = ' ';   in config.php

Comment: and then what happened. you may also need to check that the routes match up with the controllers and redirects etc.

Comment: Ya I checked ! and I referred this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615284/puzzled-using-codeigniter-on-godaddy-shared-hosting-server  but i didnt find any solution over their.The links they provided not opening

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the config ?

```
$config['base_url'] = "https://www.yoursite.com/";
```

There is a good tutorial on that at [sajjad's blog](http://sajjadhossain.com/2008/10/27/ssl-https-urls-and-codeigniter/)

Comment: still stuck.. ? your-domain.com/index.php/your-controller is accessible

Comment: Home page and some pages are opening with index.php and some pages are showing blankpage when I use index.php in URL

Comment: i have no idea,, why its so ,, can you give me the url

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615284/puzzled-using-codeigniter-on-godaddy-shared-hosting-server  My error was similar to this

Answer (score 0):

Copy the below code in your .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

my code had all class names starting with uppercase letter, however few posts mentioned changing the file name to match the class name. However, that didn't help. Finally the following helped:

create a file .htaccess and add the following lines of code in it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

it should work